# Google+ API using coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, google-plus

I have the Google+ API implemented and working with the JS API and jQuery using the following demo

> https://github.com/DieSocialisten/Hacking-Google-Plus

The current setup uses CoffeeScript along with some OO jQuery code and I need to convert this code to CoffeeScript.

Does anyone have any working demo/code of using the Google+ api written in CoffeeScript working out of a Class?

Sample code of the structure I have

```
"use strict"

require [
  "jquery"
  "app/views/common-view"
], ($, CommonView) ->
  class DemoView extends CommonView

    # init
    constructor: ->
      super

    initGplus: ->
      #Google Plus code here

  DemoView

  # start
  $ ->
    demoView = new DemoView
```

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: The difference between using the API with JavaScript and CoffeeScript will be nearly non-existent.

Comment: @muistooshort Well the flow of loading the js and generating buttons/interactive posts is a bit tricky and specially gets complicated once you throw it all in with OO concepts.

Comment: But the OO concepts in CoffeeScript are the same as in JavaScript, CS just gives you a standard way to build "classes" whereas JavaScript lets you pick which method you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Javascript to Coffeescript conversion tool like [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org)?  It may not be perfect, but it will certainly get you started.

Comment: I did try that but can't seem to get it right specially with a Class. Edited the question to include the requirement